# Arduino book recommendation

Tags: arduino, books

What book would you recommend for someone who comes from a software background that is looking to become fluent in Arduino?

I'd prefer something that walks the reader through examples, from N00b to advanced.

Comment: Do you wish to develop the Arduino platform itself or write sketches?

Comment: This question seems unconstructive (for this platform) to me, but it's got favorites, upvotes, and answers, so I'd like some community input.  Please weigh in at [Are book recommendations a good fit for this site?](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/891/are-book-recommendations-a-good-fit-for-this-site) on Meta to discuss this question's suitability.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found *Arduino Cookbook* from O'Reilly to be nice. There are also a ton of tutorials on the Web, and of course the examples that come with the dev environment.

> The recipes in this book provide solutions for most common problems
>   and questions Arduino users have, including everything from
>   programming fundamentals to working with sensors, motors, lights, and
>   sound, or communicating over wired and wireless networks. You'll find
>   the examples and advice you need to begin, expand, and enhance your
>   projects right away.
>
> - Get to know the Arduino development environment
> - Understand the core elements of the Arduino programming language
> - Use common output devices for light, motion, and sound
> - Interact with almost any device that has a remote control
> - Learn techniques for handling time delays and time measurement
> - Use simple ways to transfer digital information from sensors to the Arduino device
> - Create complex projects that incorporate shields and external modules
> - Use and modify existing Arduino libraries, and learn how to create your own

Comment: "Nice" does not adequately explain the merit of this book. Please see the post notice (in gray above) and [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) for more information

Comment: KevinVermeer's comment applies to the original, short answer. The answer is fine the way it is now. (Maybe @Kortuk can delete this comments)

Answer (score 6):

I really like these books:

1. [Getting Started with Arduino](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1449309879) - This book is like the beginner bible.  Full of explaninations, sample projects, source code, pictures, and everything else a beginner needs.  My book also came with a discount code for an arduino, printed in the back of the book.
2. [Arduino Robotics - Beginner-Advanced](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430231831) - This book is a beginners guide to Arduino robots.  When I started with arduino, I wasn't specifically interested in robots, by the projects and explanations in this book were awesome.  Worth reading, and at minimum, will give you ideas.

Also this website has **tons** of blog posts, and tutorials, etc.
[Makezine - Arduino](http://blog.makezine.com/archive/category/arduino)

Comment: "I really like" does not adequately explain the merit of this book. Please see the post notice (in gray above) and [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) for more information

Comment: Is this better ?

Comment: I would still prefer more, but it is a much better answer.

Comment: Thanks, would you mind an upvote to help get my reputation started